# Removing a fragment and moving to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Fragment "A" calls fragment "B" that in turn, calls fragment "C".

Now, i want on a click event of button in fragment "C" the fragment "C" should be removed and fragment "B" should be shown.(All the fragments are already into backstack. I am having some problem in this.) Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`?(Assuming you're using ABS).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **popBackStack();** method:

But you can work with Fragment using this proper way:

```
private static final String STATE_URI = "state:uri";
private static final String STATE_FRAGMENT_TAG = "state:fragment_tag";
private Uri currentUri = YourFragment.ABOUT_URI;
private String currentContentFragmentTag = null;
```

on Oncreate() method:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_URI));
        currentContentFragmentTag = savedInstanceState
                .getString(STATE_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }


   @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(STATE_URI, currentUri.toString());
    outState.putString(STATE_FRAGMENT_TAG, currentContentFragmentTag);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    final Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(currentContentFragmentTag);
    if (currentFragment instanceof YourDesiredFragment) {
        final YourDesiredFragment webFragment = (YourDesiredFragment) currentFragment;
        if (webFragment.onBackPressed())
            return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did already try [popBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28%29) ?